# Can I import svg into Gideros?

Tags: svg, import, graphics, gideros

Ok I will admit to being a noob with Gideros.  I am trying to import an svg file.  I followed the same procedure as you would do for a png file, that is create a texture using:

> myTexture = Texture.new("orangeSquare.svg")
>
> orangeSquare = Bitmap.new(myTexture)
>
> stage:addChild(orangeSquare)

Unsurprisingly it doesn't work (output gives orangeSquare.svg: Error while reading image file. and program does not run) as it is not a bitmap file.  Is there an alternative to import svg files?  It is probably a very simple solution but I have been searching for some time without an answer.  I am considering giving up on Gideros if I don't find an answer to what should be a simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can not import the svg directly, you need to pass the svg data:

```
--Banana shape, SVG path format
local banana = "M8.64,223.948c0,0,143.468,3.431,185.777-181.808c2.673-11.702-1.23-20.154,1.316-33.146h16.287c0,0-3.14,17.248,1.095,30.848c21.392,68.692-4.179,242.343-204.227,196.59L8.64,223.948z"
p=Path2D.new()
p:setSvgPath(banana) --Set the path from a SVG path description
p:setLineThickness(5) -- Outline width
p:setFillColor(0xFFFF80,0.7) --Fill color
p:setLineColor(0x404000) --Line color
p:setAnchorPosition(100,100)
stage:addChild(p)
```

You can find more info on their wiki: https://wiki.giderosmobile.com/index.php?search=svg&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go&fulltext=1

They also have it as a sample project when you open gideros studio.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Much apreciated!  I thought I might have to use the shape feature in order to do vector graphics.  In the end I decided just to convert the svg files to phg.  It might not scale as well as svg but it is simpler